# Integral of function y=h/(a+bx)?

Tags: integration

Apologies if it is very basic but I have some doubts.

To find the integral, do I first have to find y' i.e. differentiate the function wrt x then have $\int y dy$? Or just put $dx$ on both sides i.e. $\int ydx$ and integrate it?

Comment: It would help if you give some context.. what is the original problem and how did you arrive at this?

Comment: I am thinking of finding the total time period (sum of all y) of a particle.

Comment: I mean, the latter one, but I don’t really understand what you’re saying.

Comment: what are x and y if this is a physics problem?

Comment: Y is time and x is energy

Answer (score 2):

I am putting a very basic and detailed solution, assuming you are a beginner in calculus. Here you go!

We are given
$$y = \frac{h}{a+bx}$$
and wish to evaluate $I=\int y\,\textrm dx$.

Now, the first thing that comes to the mind is substitution.
Substitute $u=a+bx$ i.e. $\textrm du = b\,\textrm dx$ to get
$$I = \int\frac{h}{u}\,\textrm dx = \int\frac{h}{bu}\cdot b\,\textrm dx$$
$$I = \int\frac{h}{bu}\,\textrm du = \frac{h}{b}\int\frac{1}{u}\,\textrm du$$
We already know that $\int 1/x\,\textrm dx = \ln x$, hence
$$I = \frac{h\ln u}{b}$$
Substitute back the value of $u$,
$$I = \frac{h\ln (a+bx)}{b}$$
which is your answer.

Hope it helps :)